# How do I treat a fairly strong correlation of a predictor to the output variable?

Tags: correlation, interpretation, predictor

As one of  the preliminary steps in my data analysis project, I am looking at a correlation table I made of my potential predictors and one output variable. There is no significant information overlap between the predictors. (There are very weak correlations of 0 with a deviation of about +-0.05) However, two of these predictors are quite correlated with the output variable, their values are about 0.6.

I learned in class that usually you remove/combine predictors that are fairly correlated with each other, but how does this relate to a predictor correlating with the output variable? 
My instinct tells me that this might be quite a useful predictor.

Should I have not included the output variable in my correlation matrix in the first place? How do I treat these predictors?

Comment: Isn't the whole point to find variables that are strongly correlated with what you want to predict?  Why would you possibly want *not* to use those variables?

Comment: but always remember "correlation does not equal causation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be quite happy that some predictors are highly correlated with the response, that gives reason to expect successful modelling. That some predictors have correlation about 0.6  gives no reason for concern, possible problems ("multicollinearity") would only appear at much higher correlation levels.